# Google Product Feed Error (Error code: invalidRequestUri.)

Tags: magento

I’m trying to setup and add items to my Google Product Feed for running product ads.

I’ve connected my account and mapped all the required attributes. ( almost positive )

When I go to add a product to google content I am getting this error

Errors happened while adding products to Google Shopping.

Error code: invalidRequestUri. Internal reason: Invalid request URI See ‘’ for product ‘Hangar 9 1/8th Scale Military Pilot’ (in ‘Default Store View’ store)

I’m stuck on this if anyone can please help
Thanks, Dane.

Answer (score 0):

check what is the request uri.

Your product name has a special character "/" which might result in URL for this product which is invalid.
Hangar 9 1/8th Scale Military Pilot

Comment: I've tried products with no special characters and still get the same error. What exactly is a uri?

Comment: a uniform resource identifier (URI) is a string of characters used to identify a name or a web resource.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier